# When is a Connection closed when calling JooQ DSLContext's .close(), if at all?

Tags: java, postgresql, jooq

Here is the code of a class which I am writing which uses JooQ 3.7.0 (the irrelevant parts have been stripped); note the uses of the `AutoCloseable` feature of `DSLContext`:

```
public final class JooqPerMethodMetricWriter
    implements PerMethodMetricWriter
{
    private static final Logger LOGGER
        = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JooqPerMethodMetricWriter.class);

    // [snip]

    private final DSLContext jooq;

    public JooqPerMethodMetricWriter(final Connection connection,
        final Instant instant)
        throws IOException
    {
        // [snip]    
        jooq = DSL.using(connection);    
    }

    private void writeCsv(final Configuration configuration)
    {
        // [snip]    

        try (
            final DSLContext context = DSL.using(configuration);
            final Reader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(csvPath);
        ) {

            final Loader<PermethodMetricsRecord> loader = context
                .loadInto(PERMETHOD_METRICS)
                .loadCSV(reader)
                .fields(PERMETHOD_METRICS.fields())
                .execute();
            LOGGER.info("{} lines stored in database", loader.stored());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Cannot open CSV for reading", e);
        }
    // BREAKPOINT 1
    }

    @Override
    public void close()
        throws IOException
    {
        jooq.transaction(this::writeCsv);
        jooq.close();
        // BREAKPOINT 2
        Files.delete(csvPath);
    }
        // [snip]    
}
```

If relevant at all, the database used is PostgreSQL (9.4.x).

In the code above, I have two breakpoints. When I debug, I see that:

- at the first breakpoint, `configuration.connectionProvider().acquire().isClosed()` is false...
- at the second breakpoint,
  `jooq.configuration().connectionProvider().acquire().isClosed()` is *also* false.

I'm confused. What happened to the `Connection` which I have received as a constructor parameter? Do I need to `.close()` it myself?

---

Side question, this time with regards to the `Loader`: I leave the defaults, therefore `.commitNone()`; given that I run the loader within a transacation, would it make a difference at all if I tried and `.commit<somethingElse>()` instead, for instance `.commitAfter(1000)`?

Comment: May I ask you to ask the side question in a separate question here on Stack Overflow? It will be more useful for future visitors...

Comment: @LukasEder done; [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33596329/1093528).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Current answer

This question became outdated with the introduction of the [`CloseableDSLContext`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/CloseableDSLContext.html), when the `AutoCloseable` semantics was removed again from the more general-purpose `DSLContext`. The incompatible change was implemented in jOOQ 3.14, in order to address the confusion expressed in this question and a few others, see:

https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/10512

#### Historic answer

`DSLContext` became `AutoCloseable` with the Java 8 distributions of jOOQ 3.7. The [`DSLContext.close()`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/DSLContext.html#close--) method's Javadoc explains the semantics of this `close()` call:

> Close the underlying resources, if any resources have been allocated when constructing this `DSLContext`.
>
> Some `DSLContext` constructors, such as [`DSL.using(String)`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#using-java.lang.String-), [`DSL.using(String, Properties)`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#using-java.lang.String-java.util.Properties-), or [`DSL.using(String, String, String)`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#using-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) allocate a `Connection` resource, which is inaccessible to the outside of the `DSLContext` implementation. Proper resource management must thus be done via this `close()` method.

Only resources allocated when you constructed the `DSLContext` will be released. Not resources that you passed to the `DSLContext`. In your case, you are not allocating any resources in this `try-with-resources` statement, so there is nothing to be released at the end of it:

```
try (DSLContext context = DSL.using(configuration); ...) { ... }
```

This would be different if you allocated a new `Connection` right there:

```
try (DSLContext context = DSL.using("jdbc:h2:~/test", "sa", ""); ...) { ... }
```

#### Regarding your questions:

> I'm confused. What happened to the Connection which I have received as a constructor parameter?

Nothing. You must govern its lifecycle yourself as jOOQ doesn't know anything about your connection lifecycle strategy.

> Do I need to .close() it myself?

Yes.

Comment: OK, I should have read the javadoc more closely... Might I suggest that the "[...]if any resources have been allocated when constructing this DSLContext" be in bold and give examples, such as for instance the `Connection` not being closed if you use the matching `.using()` methods?

Comment: @fge: You're right. Some more examples would be useful in the Javadoc. I've created an issue for this: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/4721

Comment: Another side question then; I guess that in my code, I don't need to bother about .close()ing the created DSLContext within the `TransactionalRunnable`, right?

Comment: Erm, uh, wait, stop... What about the embedded `Configuration` if, say, I used `DSL.using(someJdbcUrl, someUser, somePassword)?

Comment: Well, in that case, do I need to explicitly close the embedded `DSLContext` which I have to create? In other words, will the outer context already have created the connection for me and I don't need to care about it, or will it create a new connection?

Comment: If you're using `DSL.using(String, String, String)`, then yes, you have to close the returned `DSLContext`. I don't know what you mean by "embedded `DSLContext`".

Comment: What I mean is that when you use a `TransactionRunnable`, or a `TransactionalCallable<T>`, you are supplied with a `Configuration` from which you must create a `DSLContext`; how will this configuration acquire a connection from the outer context, and does it vary depending on how the configuration was set up to begin with?

Comment: Good questions. I think the best way to answer is in a new Stack Overflow question, where you set up some example code illustrating this. It will be useful also for future readers.

Comment: After some thinking, does it really matter? Let me explain: you lose nothing by using try-with-resources in any case; the only thing which you need to care about is whether you pass arguments to `DSL.using(...)` which are themselves `{Auto,}Closeable` since JooQ will not handle them for you. I know that JooQ does not use JSR 305 but if you use the correct jar then you can add a provided dependency on this jar and annotate the required parameters as `@WillNotClose`.

Comment: JSR 305 is a different story. Those annotations will make matters only worse by fixing symptoms of broken language features... :) Anyway, the `Configuration` is not `AutoCloseable`, so that's why I'm confused by this discussion...