# Do the .commit*() or .batch*() methods of a JooQ's Loader<?> matter within a TransactionalRunnable?

Tags: java, postgresql, jooq

This is using JooQ 3.7.0. JooQ allows you to use its API to [import data from, for instance, a CSV](http://www.jooq.org/doc/3.7/manual-single-page/#importing-csv).

Let us take this code as an example of an implementation (in Java 8, as a method reference) of a [`TransactionalRunnable`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/3.7.x/org/jooq/TransactionalRunnable.html):

```
// csvPath is a Path to a CSV file
private void writeCsv(final Configuration configuration)
{
    try (
        final Reader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(csvPath);
    ) {
        final Loader<PermethodMetricsRecord> loader = DSL.using(configuration)
            .loadInto(PERMETHOD_METRICS)
            .loadCSV(reader)
            .fields(PERMETHOD_METRICS.fields())
            .execute();
        LOGGER.info("{} lines stored in database", loader.stored());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Cannot open CSV for reading", e);
    }
}
```

Now, the call to a `DSLContext`'s `.loadInto()` is a [`LoaderOptionStep`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/3.7.x/org/jooq/LoaderOptionsStep.html). And this class has several methods on it, in particular a default commit policy (`.commitNone()` is the default) and batch methods.

Here we are in a transaction created by JooQ; I don't specify any commit nor batch policy other than the defaults.

Does it matter at all whether I use any commit/batch policy depending on the RDBMS engine I use? Note that in my case, this is PostgreSQL 9.4.X.

Comment: What do you mean by "commit or batch policy"?

Comment: I mean that I leave the defaults, as shown in the code; I don't batch or bulk insert or anything else

Comment: Oh, I see. You meant the `Loader` API flags, obviously. My bad. I thought you were referring to some JDBC settings... Will answer soon

Answer (score 1):

As of jOOQ 3.7, the behaviour of using jOOQ's transaction API along with anything other than `commitNone()` (the default) on the `Loader` API is *undefined*.

The `Loader` API will commit batches directly on the underlying JDBC connection, but this can behave differently, depending on how you produce this connection (e.g. via a connection pool, etc.)

There is a pending feature request to specify and implement a predictable behaviour:
https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/4770